# Explain this Towers of Hanoi solution (written in python)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to understand this particular solution of Towers of Hanoi problem. It is a recursive solution.

```
A = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
B = []
C = []

def move(n, source, target, auxiliary, frm):
print('n here : ', n)
if n > 0:
    print('frm : ', frm, n)

    # move n - 1 disks from source to auxiliary, so they are out of the way
    move(n - 1, source, auxiliary, target, '1')

    # move the nth disk from source to target
    target.append(source.pop())

    print('n:', n)

    # Display our progress
    print(source, target, auxiliary, '##############', sep = '\n')

    # move the n - 1 disks that we left on auxiliary onto target
    move(n - 1, auxiliary, target, source, '2')

# initiate call from source A to target C with auxiliary B
move(5, A, C, B, '0')
```

You can see it live here
https://repl.it/JUzY/0

After the first line of ######### gets printed, the value of n = 0, becomes 2. How does this happen? Am I missing out some concept of recursion ? Help me in understanding this.

Comment: read it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution

Comment: I have read and understood it, but I am trying to understand this particular logic. How the recursion is working here ?

Comment: you are calling the same procedure, `move`, to solve a smaller problem, `n-1`, as part of the current procedure of solving the bigger problem, `n`.

Comment: so if our `move` procedure works, we can call it. assume it works for smaller `n`s. use it. then construct the solution for the current, bigger problem, from *solutions* to the smaller problems. this proves that `move` works as expected. (of course, need to take care of the base case too...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand *scope*. You say "the value of n = 0, but suddenly it becomes 2". But there is more than one "n", because the *scope* of n is the method. Each time `move` gets called, that method call has its own instance of `n` with its own value.

At the bottom of the script, you call `move(5, A, C, B, '0')`. Inside that call, `n == 5`. The first thing that does is call `move(n - 1, source, auxiliary, target, '1')`. Inside *that* call, `n == 4`. But when it eventually returns, `n` in the original function call is still `5`.

---

A good way to understand how recursion works, is to work through the program execution by hand, using sheets of paper. I'm going to use a Post-It note for function calls, and a notebook for output. You also have your "model", in the form of the lists `A,B,C`. Since elements move around, you could represent those elements with scraps of paper or scrabble tiles.

Start with the intial `move(4, A, C, B, '0')`. (I'm starting at 4 because the number of steps grows rapidly). Since we are calling a function, take a new post-it to represent the function call, and write on it:

```
n = 4
source = A
target = C
auxiliary = B
frm = '0'
```

Now work through the code of `move` doing what it says. Write any `print` output on this one.

When you reach the call to `move(n - 1, source, auxiliary, target, '1')`, make a note on the post-it of the line number you're at, then get a new post-it, and write the values that are going into it:

```
n = 4     (because 4 - 1)
source = A
target = B  (caller's auxiliary)
auxiliary = C (caller's target)
frm = '1'
```

Place this **on top of** the previous post-it. You are not allowed to look at the covered up post-it until it's revealed again. Keep doing this, and you'll end up with a stack of five post-its.

The fifth post-it has `n = 0`. Now when you step through its code, because it starts with `if n > 0:`, the call returns immediately. This function call is over, so tear up that one post-it and throw it away. The values of `n` etc. in that post-it **have no effect on the other post-its**.

You made a note of the line-number you were at, so carry on executing the code by hand from that line. You will produce some output, then call `move` again -- use post-its for this move too, again covering up the current post-it and growing your stack until you make a call with `n == 0` and can remove an item from the stack.

If you keep doing this, you'll see the stack grow and shrink several times, you'll reach the original post-it once, do its print, then grow the stack again, then reach the original post-it again, and finally finish.

---

The stack of post-it notes is an exact model of the *execution stack* of a program's runtime. When you see stack traces (even of non-recursive programs), this is what they represent. Each post-it is a *stack frame*, and local variables have a scope that is restricted to that stack frame.

---

The recursive solution to Hanoi can be expressed in English as:

- To move a stack of size zero, do nothing
- To move a bigger stack from src to destination via auxiliary:

  - First move n-1 discs from src to auxiliary (to get them out of the way)

    - do that the same way we are doing this.
  - Then move the revealed disc to destination
  - Then move the n-1 discs from auxiliary to destination, using src as a spare peg

    - do that the same way we are doing this